# ¿porqué una regla CORS definida en el .htaccess es como si no existiera cuando realizo una llamada desde PostMan?

Tags: cors, postman

He difinido una regla CORS en el .htaccess pero ocurre que cuando realizo la llamada desde el programa Postman esta regla no funciona, es como si no existiera, en cambio si realizo la llamada desde la aplicación web, entonces sí se aplica la regla y no recibo respuesta.

Las preguntas son: 
1.- ¿porqué con el programa Postman esta regla es como si no existiera?
2.- ¿en algún lugar del postman se han definido url que después en la petición se añaden a la cabecera ?

Saludos.

Comment: el [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) basicamente hace un llamado al OPTIONS para verificar que metodos de solicitud son soportados , una vez ejecutado , llama a los metodos "GET,POST, PUT,PATCH .....etc", si cambias tu POSTMAN a metodo OPTIONS tendras el problema de CORS(el navegador ejecuta las dos solicitudes, el options y luego el metodo que realmente necesitas)

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta.

ahora bien, me pregunto también que si estoy utilizando el PostMan en la versión Free, entonces es posible que desde la propia empresa PostMan "podrían" acceder a los servicios que yo estoy desarrollando?.

Comment: Muchas gracias.
¿Si uso el PostMan( versión free), es posible que desde la empresa PostMan "podrían" acceder a los servicios que he desarrollando?.Tienen todas las peticiones, u otra persona que analice las llamadas a la apirest desde la herramienta developer(F12, por ejemplo) de Chrome y copie las  url a otra instalación de PostMan. ¿o estoy equivocado?

Si es cierto, ¿cómo podría mejorar la seguridad del servidor donde están alojados los servicios apirest para que sólo se puedan realizar llamadas desde el postman que está instalado en mi equipo?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: ¿Sería añadiendo la siguiente regla en el .htaccess?

<Limit GET POST>
 order deny,allow
 deny from all
 allow from ip del servidor web
 allow from ip del equipo de desarrollo
</Limit>

Comment: Salvador lo que comenta es sujeta a opiniones, no creo que POSTMAN se preocupe por ver los servicios que estas desarrollando, la otra pregunta cualquier persona con un navegador puede acceder a la consola, ni google se salva y lo podemos hacer con chrome (que es de  google)  en cuanto a seguridad para api recomiendan manejar las sessiones con token tambien puedes bloquear ip por geolocalizacion con apache/nginx o usar un proxy o las herramientas de AWS

Comment: por lo pronto si quieres que resolvamos tu problema de .htaccess manejalo, esta pregunta como esta, es sujeta a opiniones ,trata de explicar mas el problema que tienes y como lo intentastes solucionar

Comment: Muchas gracias.... lo pensaré.
De momento utilizo en todos los servicios token+jwt.

Si duda tendré que mejorar la seguridad...

Comment: marcare tu pregunta como "basada en opiniones" de igual maneras ,te invito a hacer el [tour] y leer el [como preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)